# Can spawned Postgresql process be controlled by the spawner PHP script?

Tags: php, linux, postgresql, command-line, ubuntu

I have a PHP CLI script, that processes a csv file, inserting it's content to a table in Postgresql database. This is on an Ubuntu server. I use schedtool to control the affinity of the whole script. Schedtool is used to launch the script itself with the -e option. Unfortunately with htop I see that the database thread is spawned as a completely different thread and being not affected by the affinity options.

Is it possible to somehow make the database process inherit all affinity options from the spawner PHP script?

---

I have just found the answer -as I was reading some Postgresql example files for Ruby :).

My best choice would be to get the very exact PID of the Postgresql thread that is running the current script, with NOTIFY - LISTEN.
As [depesz] told Postgres uses only 1 core. With `schedtool` I still can control on which core it runs and with `cpulimit` I can control it further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Postgres doesn't use threads.  Each connection is handled by a single threaded process.  So, a single connection can only use one core.  Though the OS may move it to different cores, it will only use one at a time.

If you insist on nicing postgres, "SELECT pg_backend_pid()" will give you the PID of the postgres process without any NOTIFY/LISTEN stuff.  Though, in general, you don't want to try to nice a postgres process.  You may cause other higher priority processes to block.  Then what you thought was a low priority process isn't so low-priority any more.

If you're just doing a bunch of inserts from a csv, nicing your script probably won't help much.  Postgres is probably doing more of the work, and it's probably IO, so again, nicing may not get you much.  You could, however, sleep every once in a while.  Insert for 50 milliseconds, sleep for a while, ...

Comment: Thank you very much! I have again learned so much :) Now I restructure my script and adapt the new thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Postgres backend is always spawned from postmaster process, so there is no way to pass affinity (whatever that would be) options from php script to postgres backend.

On the other hand - if you'd describe what affinity is, and what kind of options you want to setup/pass, maybe there is a solution - the fact that there is no general solution, doesn't mean that there isn't specialized solution for some things.

Comment: Certainly. Schedtool sets the CPU scheduling parameters for a given process. For instance, in my case I set the process to use only 1 core of the 2 on my CPU. This is called affinity. I can set the NICE level too.

For more read: http://linux.die.net/man/8/schedtool

Comment: Client application cannot set nice level on server - in your situation php app cannot set nice level on postgresql backend.

As for setting whether an application can use 1 or 2 cores - there is not much point in it, as 1 PostgreSQL backend will always use only 1 core.

Comment: So, I should not bother with the separate postgres thread as it will only use 1 core all the time?
This would be nice, as my goal is to minimize the overall load. Could you possibly recommend some documentation, tutorial on this matter (Postgres load balancing), please?